# Voice Intensity calculation in android

Tags: android, audiorecord

I created an sample application for searching anything in web through voice command like google search. I used `import android.media.AudioRecord;` for this. While the user says i am showing an animation on the Icon based on the intensity of the voice. For that i have done a math calculation which i got from internet. I am getting the wrong command if i am doing this calculation. Please help me to find the reason for that.

Please see my code.

```
minBufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize( 8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
rec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, 8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 8192);
```

//Recoding starting here

```
   public void run() {
        rec.startRecording();
        while (!done) {
            int nshorts = readBlock();
            if (nshorts <= 0)
                break;
        }
        rec.stop();
        rec.release();
    }
```

// readBlock() method. Calculation does here

```
       int readBlock() {
       short[] buf = new short[this.block_size];
       byte audioBuffer[]      = new  byte[this.minBufferSizeInBytes];
        float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
           short sample = 0;
           int numberOfReadBytes = 0; 
           float tempFloatBuffer[] = new float[3];
           int tempIndex = 0;

       int nshorts = rec.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
       if (nshorts > 0) {
            q.add(buf);
       }
       numberOfReadBytes = rec.read( audioBuffer, 0,minBufferSizeInBytes );
        for( int i=0; i<numberOfReadBytes; i+=2 ) {
            sample = (short)( (audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8 );
            if(sample!=0) {
                totalAbsValue += Math.abs( sample ) / (numberOfReadBytes/2);
            }
        }
        tempFloatBuffer[tempIndex%3] = totalAbsValue;
        temp = 0.0f;
        for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
            temp += tempFloatBuffer[i];
        System.out.println("Temp: "+temp);
        mMyClass = MyClass.getInstance();
        mMyClass.handler.postDelayed(mMyClass.AnimateRunnable, 100);
        return nshorts;
 }
```